# Matlab element position

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm rewriting the question that I did few days ago because I messed up with the explanation of what I wanna do.

I've got a U/V coordinate system that I built in Matlab using `meshgrid` between the values (-0.1,0.1). For sake of semplicity I converted this system to the [theta-phi coordinate system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/uv2phitheta.html).
This conversion give me me two new matrices that I called A, B that are of this kind.

```
A=. . . . .   B= . . . . .
  . . . . .      . . . . .
  . . 0 . .      . . 0 0 0
  . . . . .      . . . . .
  . . . . .      . . . . .
```

Points represent values in radians but the important point is that A has a zero in the middle while B has half central row equal to 0 and the other half another value in radians. In my case these matrix are 201x201 large.
This means that in a graphic way I should have this kind of grid:
[image]

and each point assumes a specific value in a third matrix. What I need to do is collect the element of this third matrix at a specific point. For example I need the point (in the UV system) 0.005,0.005 like this:
[image]

What I thought to do is using this function

```
function [out_matrix] = find_value(in_matrix,ref_matrix_H,ref_matrix_V,ref)

ref_matrix= sqrt(ref_matrix_H.^2+ref_matrix_V.^2);
[value,ii] = min(abs(ref_matrix(:)-ref));
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(ref_matrix),ii);

out_matrix=in_matrix(row,col);

end
```

where `ref_matrix_H` and `ref_matrix_V` are  the two matrices A, B; ref is one of the two point that I need. I compute this `ref_matrix` like intersection of the two matrices and compare each element of this new matrix with my value and therefore take the coordinates of the corrisponding element but this function does not extract the correct values that I expect.

I think that the problem is when I compute `ref_matrix` because what I get as result is something like this:

```
ref_matrix= 0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700
            0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650
            0.500 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.500
            0.450 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.450
            0.350 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.350
            0.450 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.450
            0.500 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.500
            0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650
            0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700
```

where the central elements are very small (which is correct) and the others increase going far from the center. To work properly the matrix should have another form anyway

```
ref_matrix= -0.700 -0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700
            -0.650 -0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650
            -0.500 -0.005 0.005 0.005 0.500
            -0.450 -0.002 0.002 0.002 0.450
            -0.350 -0.001 0.001 0.001 0.350
            -0.450 -0.002 0.002 0.002 0.450
            -0.500 -0.005 0.005 0.005 0.500
            -0.650 -0.650 0.650 0.650 0.650
            -0.700 -0.700 0.700 0.700 0.700
```

Comment: So `ref` is a location in the U/V coordinate system? Or in the phi-theta coordinate system? If the code you post it looks like it is a scalar value, but that doesn't give you a location.

Comment: `ref` in in phi/theta radians.  Using some breackpoints it looks like that this function extract the first element that finds close to `ref` which obviously is wrong. Actually I have 2 "refs", one regarding A and the other regarding B, but since in the main I have 2 `in_matrix` one for the vertical and the other for horizontal values, I thought that I could give just the corrispondent ref value. What I expect to have in output are the coordinates near the center of this "reference system" but it looks that this function takes the first element close to the value of `ref`

Comment: I might get where is the problem. When I compute `ref_matrix` with Pitagora theorem, I get a symmetry arount the central column. Therefore when I go to check which is the element closest to `ref`, it takes the first that finds (which is in the left of the matrix, where the correct one should be the one on the right). I should find a way to have still a symmetric matrix around the central column, but a sign difference between the two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ref` is a two-element vector containing the theta and phi values, corresponding to `ref_matrix_H` and `ref_matrix_V`, I would do something like this to find the integer index closest to those coordinates:

```
function out_value = find_value(in_matrix,ref_matrix_H,ref_matrix_V,ref)
   dist_matrix = sqrt((ref_matrix_H-ref(1)).^2 + (ref_matrix_V-ref(2)).^2);
   [~,index] = min(dist_matrix(:));
   out_value = in_matrix(index);
end
```

What I did here was change your code so that `dist_matrix` is the distance in `H-V` space to `ref` (note this is always a positive value). The original code transformed the `H-V` space into a distance to the origin, and found a distance value that was closest to one of the values in `ref`.

The minimum index can directly be used to retrieve the value in `in_matrix` using linear indexing. You can use `ind2sub` to get the row and column index, but it is not necessary in this case.

---

**EDIT**

> I need the point (in the UV system) 0.005,0.005

If you are dealing with UV coordinates, simply use those. You've generated a U and V matrix using `meshgrid`, this means that it's a nice coordinate system to work in (monotonically increasing coordinates in both directions). `interp2` will then simplify your work:

```
% Your data (mock-up):
[U,V] = meshgrid(linspace(-0.1,0.1,201),linspace(-0.1,0.1,201));
in_matrix = randn(201,201);

% Query a point (u,v):
u = 0.005;
v = 0.005;
out = interp2(U,V,in_matrix,u,v);
```

`interp2` uses linear interpolation by default. If you really need to get the one element from `in_matrix` that is closest to the coordinates, use nearest-neighbor interpolation:

```
out = interp2(U,V,in_matrix,u,v,'nearest');
```

Comment: (note I didn't try to run the code, please let me know if it is not correct.)

Comment: `ref` is a scalar not a vector. Since I've got two `ref` one for theta and the other for phi I've replaced `ref(1)` and 2 with these two scalar but they shift `dist_matrix` on the right and therefore is not symmetric around the central row and column anymore. By symmetrical I mean geometrically (like axis of symmetry) not like a symmetric matrix. To work properly I need this kind of symmetry with probably a sign change.

Comment: @Shika93: What do you mean with shifting? If you enter `phi=0` and `theta=0`, do you not get the central element? Oh, I see, if you select coordinates exactly half-way between grid elements, on the left half-plane you'll get rounded away from the origin, and on the right half-plane towards the origin (or vice-versa). Is it likely that you hit exactly half-way between samples? The only solution there is to use proper interpolation.

Comment: Maybe I lost something explaining how the matrices are. `ref_matrix_H` has its axis of symmetry around the central row, while for `ref_matrix_V` is around the central column. Means that in the two parts of the matrices there is a change of sign but the values are are the same. What I think I need is this `dist_matrix ` but maintaing this kind of symmetry. I think a matrix that can represent the classical cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: You cannot represent 2D coordinates using 1 value.

Comment: @Shika93: See my edited answer. I'm suggesting a different way of working to simplify things.